# Primefaces pdf generator multiple tables

Tags: jsf, primefaces, datatable

I recently started using PrimeFaces dataExporter to generate pdfs. I am in need of not only inserting one of my data tables into the pdf but multiple. I am also in need of writing more information into the pdf.

I did research and it looks like there is still no implementation for multiple tables. Someone please confirm this. However, is it possible to write data to the pdf?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do this in the PrimeFaces dataExporter, but you can in the one that comes with PrimeFaces Extensions.

use this link

> http://www.primefaces.org/showcase-ext/sections/exporter/multipleTables.jsf

Comment: Correct I saw that but how do I include PrimeFaces Extensions library? Is that a separate jar file?

Comment: are you using maven or jars in classpath?

Comment: jars in the classpath

Comment: ok then you need to download primefaces extension jar. google it you will get it and include in your classpath. its different jar than primefaces jar

Comment: recently i used it its wonderful feature provided by primefaces community