# Primefaces dataExporter footer issue for PDF

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I have an issue with primefaces `dataExporter` not  showing the `footer` of the `dataTable` when exporting to PDF. the header is exported but not the footer. it works fine with excel.

let's assume this is my dataTable

```
<p:dataTable id="tbl" var="product" value="#{bean.productList}">
<p:column>
    <f:facet name="header">
       <h:outputText value="Product" />
    </f:facet>
    <h:outputText value="#{product.name}" />
    <f:facet name="footer">
        <h:outputText value="Total" />
    </f:facet>
</p:column>

<p:column>
    <f:facet name="header">
       <h:outputText value="Price" />
    </f:facet>
    <h:outputText value="#{product.price}" />
    <f:facet name="footer">
        <h:outputText value="#{bean.totalPrice}" />
    </f:facet>
</p:column>

</p:dataTable>

  <h:commandLink>
            <p:graphicImage name="/demo/images/pdf.png" />
            <p:dataExporter type="pdf" target="tbl" fileName="products" />
  </h:commandLink>
```

when i export to PDF i get all my data fine except for the footer of the dataTable which contain the Total Price for the products.

What am i doing wrong ?

I'm using jsf 2.2 and primefaces 5.0

Comment: i cannot say this is answer but you can use as an alternative for your problem, you can use "primefaces extension" and its exporter tag please check below link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32343783/primefaces-pdf-generator-multiple-tables/32350352#32350352

Comment: Or try a newer version of PF (and normally before asking this is always good to to as well as to check the PrimeFaces issue list, blog, release notes etc)

Comment: I have to use the version 5.0 cause it's imposed for me. and i searched for this issue before as you suggested but i found nothig so i came here. For primefaces extension i tried it but i have an issue. it doesn't recognize the methods in my bean. i use those methods to manipulate my data before showing them. the version i tried is 2.1.0 cause its the one that works with PF 5.0